# How to fill a update form with values using :APP_USER id in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a classic report which shows profile details of a user. There is "Update Profile" button on the top of the report which when clicked redirects a user to a form from which the user can update information. I want to populate the fields in the form with the present data of the user

If I had used interactive report than I could have passed the "student_id" to the target form page. In classic report I cannot do so. I tried passing the :APP_USER instead of "student_id" but that didn't work. How can I solve this issue.

It would be better if the form can fill itself with the :APP_USER id without passing the id from the report

How can I do so?

I tried doing it by passing where clause in Source section as show in the bellow pic:
[image]

It didn't work. The form is still empty

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the form region attributes, under "Source", there is an attribute "Where Clause". You can use that to only retrieve the row for the currently logged on user.
Example:

```
  username = :APP_USER
```

Replace "username" with the column name in your table

Comment: It didn't work. I have updated my question to include some pics.

Comment: I just re-read your question. You can perfectly link to a form by passing an id from a classic report. Just define the column type as link. 
As to why it didn't work - I think it is up to you from here... debug your page using the debug option and investigate the debug log. That might give you some clues as to why it is not working in your particular case.

Comment: I don't want to pass id from report to form. I want the form to get student id from :APP_USER and population it self with the users profile data. How may i do so? Even if I try to pass id from report, inside Behavior>Target>Set Items>Value I cannot select any columns. Even if i change the type to link, it automatically reverts back to "plain text". Thank you.

Comment: In that case you should pursue the suggested solution.